# Why is chrome browser NOT rendering img src "URL" but will render the same photo in local storage?

Tags: html, url, src

I'm extracting the URL with several techniques using ing FB and twitter as the site.. and I'm 100 percent I have the right URL because each technique I use produces the same URL. its a simple `img` tag in the body of the HTML with a `src` and `alt` that's it. I'm at a loss because I can't find out why this is happening... here is the code.

```
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Zachary Henderson Professional Portfolio</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <img src="https://www.instagram.com/p/Brua7ssnfO1/" alt="Baccon Wrapped Cod">
   <h1>Zachary Henderson</h1>
   <p><em>Founder and Opperator of <b>Glossy Glass</b> </em></p>

   <hr>
   <h3>
     Experience & Projects
   </h3>

   <hr>
   <h3>My Hobbies</h3>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: `https://www.instagram.com/p/Brua7ssnfO1/` Isn't an image, it's a page. The URL for the image on that page is `https://scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/c26ba3f2a9ab179d742fb6dfbcbd6196/5E5895F3/t51.2885-15/e35/46876915_365582370842018_3088773004967453983_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-iad3-1.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=102`

Answer (score 1):

In order to load an image from a URL, you have to give a direct link to the image.

The link you're trying to load an image from is an Instagram photo link, not the direct link to the image.

To load images from Instagram, you may look at the [User Endpoints](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) from Instagram.